# Queue order of node.js callbacks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, io, callback

Are callbacks inserted into the callback queue in some sort of 'stale' state as soon as their asynchronous I/O process begins, or are they queued up only after the asynchronous I/O completes?

In otherwords, if a node server runs the following

1. Start I/O #1
2. Start I/O #2
3. Finish I/O #2
4. Finish I/O #1
5. Begin callback phase of event loop.

Which callback would run first?  The callback from I/O #1, or the callback from I/O #2?

Edited to add number ordering to the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it only runs once the async process has returned data. Think of a callback as a separate function that gets passed on and only used at the end of a piece of code.

This is what most nodeJS developers have to deal with; bringing some order to the async event loop.

The sequence in which these callbacks will run is completely up to the process time of each method called.

For instance, if the method of callback#1 take 2.5ms to complete and the method of callback#2 takes only 1ms. then Callback#2 will always return first if you run the two methods one after the other.

Comment: 'then Callback#2 will always return first if you run the two methods one after the other.'

This is true even if both the callbacks get run in the same phase?   

I.E. i'm more interested in .000.. ms differences in completion in this instance.

Comment: Pretty much yes. if you want to delay the execution of one of the functions, then look into the setImmediate() methods. it provides a way to inject a function to run at a later stage. 
If you want to check on the ms differences , I use moment to capture the start time and end time of a callback function and then log to difference in ms or us.

Comment: can you provide documentation on this?  Because i think maybe we are talking about two different things. 
The problem with using moment is that it's a JS include, which i'm fairly sure means it will not be able to log when I/O processes are completed and when callback's are queued.  It will probably only be able to log when I/O processes are queued and when callbacks are being run?